ActiveMQ Classic very slow with durable topic subscribers
We changed from normal, non-durable subscriptions to durable subscriptions in our ActiveMQ Classic instance to allow users to reconnect their WebSocket so they get all messages they missed. At first this works perfect. We added the ack frames to tell the topic when an message was received and all messages are acked just fine.
We also added the offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout and the offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule, as well as the <policyEntry topic=">" expireMessagesPeriod="120000"/> configurations described here.
They are cleaned periodically. We saw that in the control panel.
However, at some point (actually this happens very fast) the whole server gets slower and slower to a point where it doesn't really do anything anymore. Everything loads very slow etc.
We tried to deploy ActiveMQ on a server with an Docker image as well as an AWS instance. All metrics tell us that the servers seem to be bored. The CPU or RAM is not high. The traffic is not high. Nothing tells us why the ActiveMQ instance starts to be that slow.
We also tried the application on a RabbitMQ server and everything works perfectly on it, so i guess it has to be some sort of server configuration I am not aware of on ActiveMQ Classic.
Does anybody have experience with that behaviour or with durable subscriptions in general?

How many topics?

There are sometimes thousands of topics created, yet they hold no messages anymore as the subscribers have acked the messages and are gone, they are just not cleaned realy fast. When we have non durable subscribers the same topic amount is not a problem at all. It only starts to be a problem when the subscribers become durable

Try limiting the number of destinations deleted per-sweep. This allows the broker to quickly find a group inactive destinations, delete them and move on without having to scan all the destinations every pass.   <broker .. maxPurgedDestinationsPerSweep="128" .. > ref: https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/documentation/delete-inactive-destinations

Sadly it didn't help. It has the same behaviour.
